# configure cec-client on linux

Tags: linux, hdmi, linux-device-driver

My goal is to connect my linux laptop to my smart TV and to "control" the laptop with the TV remote.

I have connected the two devices with an HDMI cable and installed cec-utils Ubuntu package.

Is this enough? I don't think so. In the laptop, I run from shell:

```
$cec-client -l
libCEC version: 4.0.4, compiled on Linux-4.4.0-generic ... , features: P8_USB, DRM, P8_detect, randr, Exynos, A0CEC
Found devices: NONE
```

why no devices are detected? what am I missing?

Th TV is Samsung, if that matters.

Answer (score 2):

Probably already irrelevant to you but you'll need a CEC adaptor. Your laptop's GPU used for HDMI output most likely doesn't support the CEC API. There are a few HDMI CEC Adaptors that allow you to essentially 'bridge' your laptop and TV's connection.

You can then use the hardware on the adaptor to interface with the TV on your laptop's behalf.

If you google 'HDMI CEC Adaptors' you'll find a bunch of options.